# Redundant super interface warning in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Why could this construct generate an error/warning in Eclipse? I understand for what it will generate a report, but I guess there must be some rationale, what can go wrong, if you spell out those redundant super interfaces.

Example:

```
interface I1{
    void boo();
}


class A implements I1 {
    public void boo() {}
}


class B extends A implements I1 {
    public void boo() {}
}
```

The warning is in B, near **implements I1**.

Comment: This is probably a configuration issue, my eclipse doesn't give me warnings for redundant `implements`.

Comment: Yes, you can switch on/off this warning. That's why I used *could*.

Comment: It isn't very different from unused variable. It doesn't cause a problem on its own but it could indicate a mistake. For instance, you meant to implement an interface with the same name in a different package. Not very useful.

Comment: Your example should produce errors instead of warnings as you reduce method visibility! I1.boo is implicitly public and you reduce visibility to package level in A as well as B...

Answer (score 3):

Imaging if class `A` implement `I1` and class `B` extends `A`. By default `B` implements `I1` even though it does not need to implement any method in `I1`. If `A` were to change to implement `I2`, `B` would still compile.

However, if `B` explicitly `implements I1` but does not provide the methods, then this change would cause `B` to no longer compile.

Of course, I am ignoring the issues of users of `B` that might be assuming that `B` implements `I1`. Let's assume for this case that that is not an issue.

Answer (score 3):

It's only a warning, and I guess it has two reasons:

- it's redundant, and can thus be removed. The less noise you have the better it is. But this is a matter of style
- it tells you that you don't need to implement any of the interface method in B, since they're already implemented in A. And implementing the interface methods would thus not only implement the interface, but also override the default implementation in the superclass.